# setInterval method didn't execute while touch scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, setinterval, canvasjs

I have update the chart dynamically using setInterval method. When i run the sample it's working but while scroll the chart using touch the setInterval method didn't trigger that mean that method has been hold.. why it has been happen?

```
// update chart after specified time.
            setInterval(function () { updateChart();}, 10);
```

Please find the sample link,
http://jsfiddle.net/eNkLz/50/

Comment: https://johnresig.com/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Answer (score 0):

This is what it's designed to do.

Javascript is single-threaded, meaning asynchronous events such as `setInterval` are only run when there’s an opening in the execution.

Your scroll event is blocking the progress of execution, so other asynchronous events (ie `setInterval`) will not be run.

Comment: there is any possible to prevent that?

Comment: and one more doubt is how it's run while touch scroll? http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/chart-api/benchmark